# Apache, MySQL are not executing...!

Tags: mysql, apache, xampp

I am facing the below problem while starting Apache, MySQL as well, what to do?

Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly. This may be due to a blocked port,
       missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by            another method. Press the logs button to view error logs and check the Windows  Event viewer for more clues. 
 in log got a error: log file cannot find

How can I make it execute?

Comment: You need to provide some more specific log output, because we can't tell anything from this provided information, it is a general response.

Comment: it got installed, thank you for your response.

Comment: But the php code is displaying its not executing.?

Comment: do you have php mod installed? `libapache2-mod-php5` ?